# How to get type of property using System.Reflection.Metadata?

Tags: c#, reflection, metadata

I'm using [System.Reflection.Metadata](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Metadata) to enumerate some assemblies and pull out some information. For instance, I need to locate a type and then get information about its properties (name and type). I can find the type, find the property, but I can't figure out how to determine the *type* of the property. Here's what I have so far:

```
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(assemblyPath))
using (PEReader reader = new PEReader(stream))
{
    TypeDefinition type = ...;
    var properties = (from handles in type.GetProperties()
                      let prop = metadata.GetPropertyDefinition(handles)
                      let accessors = prop.GetAccessors()
                      let getter = metadata.GetMethodDefinition(accessors.Getter)
                      where getter.Attributes.HasFlag(MethodAttributes.Public)
                      select new
                      {
                          Name = prop.Name,
                          //Type=prop. ??? getter. ??? What to do here?
                      });

    foreach (var prop in properties)
        yield return prop;
}
```

For now I will simply load up the type using actual reflection in order to get the properties. But I'd rather use the metadata stuff instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably too late for you, but if someone else comes along, here's an answer:

`prop.Signature` is the type of the property and you can call `prop.DecodeSignature(...)` with an `ISignatureTypeProvider` of your choice (you will most likely have to implement one though)

The reason why its so complex is that the property type can refer to generic parameters of the containing type. The `System.Reflection.Metadata` library is low level and doesn't come with an integrated type system so the first thing you want to do is decide how to translate types into something you can use, and implement `ISignatureTypeProvider` accordingly.